# Singleton http client

Tags: go

I am creating a class with functions to call some apis, so far I have:

```
var client *http.Client

func getClient() *http.Client {
    if client == nil {
        client = &http.Client{
            Timeout: time.Second * 30,
            Transport: &http.Transport{
                Dial: (&net.Dialer{
                Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
                KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
            }).Dial,
            TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
            },
        }
    }
    return client
}
```

Then create a function that executes a call:

```
func CallRestApi(request Request) (response Response) {
    getClient()
    req, err := http.NewRequest(request.Method, url, bytes.NewBuffer(request.Params))
    
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    ...
}
```

I am not sure if this way I create a singleton `client` instance so that from any module that executes this function the instance will be used if it already exists.

Comment: You may want to reach for a [`sync.Once`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Once) initialization.

Comment: There's no logic involved in `getClient()`, why not just initialize `client` once with a composite literal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution creates a single `http.Client` instance **if** you only call `getClient()` from a single goroutine.

If you're calling it from multiple goroutines, then it's a data race and thus undefined behavior.

You may init your `client` as part of the package initialization, and if you're only reading it from then on, you'll be safe:

```
var client = getClient()
```

If you can't or don't want to do this, only at a later time, then initialize your `client` using [`sync.Once`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Once), and you'll be safe for concurrent use:

```
var (
    once   sync.Once
    client *http.Client
)

func initClient() {
    once.Do(func() {
        client = &http.Client{
            Timeout: time.Second * 30,
            Transport: &http.Transport{
                Dial: (&net.Dialer{
                    Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
                    KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
                }).Dial,
                TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
            },
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: For example, I have a Modulo_Test1 and Modulo_Test2, both of which will implement and call the CallRestApi function, which in turn executes getClient and checks if client is initialized. With var client = getClient () would it suffice that, regardless of which module calls it, it will take the value if it already exists?

Comment: @sioesi It's not a matter of which module calls it, it's a matter of which _goroutine_. If multiple goroutines access the same variable and at least one of the accesses is a write, explicit synchronization is required.

Comment: Go's `http.Client` is safe for concurrent access.

Comment: @squiguy Yes, it is, but no variable is safe for concurrent access, including the `client` variable. The issue here is reading and writing the `client` variable itself, not using the `http.Client` value.

Comment: @squiguy I understand, but I wanted to create a client with that specific configuration, if I didn't create it as a variable, would I have to create that configuration every time I use it?

Comment: @sioesi Creating a variable with that specific configuration is OK. The question is _when_ you create it and _how_ / _who_ accesses it. If the `client` variable is accessed from other goroutines than the one that creates (writes) it, synchronization is required to ensure reads happen after the write.

Comment: @icza No, it will never be accessed from other routes, it will always be the same. From other routes I call the CallRestApi function which is in the same package as getClient

Comment: @sioesi Modules and packages have nothing to do with goroutines. The same package may launch multiple goroutines, and multiple packages and modules may use a single goroutine.

Comment: I understand, I think I will have to study that better before concluding this code

Comment: @sioesi If you're unsure whether your project uses multiple goroutines, stay on the safe side and make your code safe for concurrent use. Initialize the variable like `var client = getClient()` or with a compositle literal, or if there's more to the initialization process, use `sync.Once`.

Comment: @icza, what is the point of initializing an `http.Client` this way, instead of using a composite literal?

Comment: @BurakSerdar I was "extending" the asker's code. If this is the exact code he uses to initialize `client`, I would just initialize the variable with a composite literal at declaration.

Comment: I made a small example, run `go myfunction()` followed by `myfunction()` with the code for my question and print inside `getClient()` an example text "initialized client". It was printed 2 times "initialized client", while with once.Do only the first calling

Answer (score 3):

Here's an easier way of doing it:

```
var Client *http.Client= &http.Client{
            Timeout: time.Second * 30,
            Transport: &http.Transport{
                Dial: (&net.Dialer{
                Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
                KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
            }).Dial,
            TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
            },
        }
    }
```

You do not need a separate initializer function to initialize a variable.